# In UIInputView subclass systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:) is not called

Tags: ios, uikit

I’m creating a `UIInputView` subclass. The docs for `allowsSelfSizing` say

> When the value of this property is false (the default), UIKit
>   determines an appropriate size of the input view based on its current
>   layout. When the value of this property is true, UIKit honors the
>   value returned by the systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:) method of the input
>   view.

So I’ve set `allowsSelfSizing = true` in `init` but `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)` is never called. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Litehouse No I ended up overriding `intrinsicContentSize` to return a fixed height.

Comment: I set a height constraint on the inputView with high priority.  That seems to work fine. I believe that property may work when the keyboard is not a keyboard extension.

Comment: I was not creating a custom keyboard extension.

Comment: Nice to know.  I suppose they had good intentions. ;-)